# Stopping values from rounding to whole numbers in ArcGIS attribute tables?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, editing

I am trying to edit an attribute table in ArcGIS 10.1 and so far have been unable to keep it from rounding to whole numbers.  Even when I manage to "pad with zeroes" using the numeric settings, it will round to 6.0. I have tried the Editor > Options > General method as well.  My decimal places are currently set to round to 6, but any data I enter rounds to a whole number.  My field is set to "Long Integer".

What obvious solution am I missing?

Answer (score 11):

'Long integer' won't produce decimals. Try floating point. For reference, [this wiki link lists types of numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_numbers).